# Understanding Row and Column Layouts

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to understand why does not this example draw any `Rectangle`s when displaying it with `qmlscene` ? Is it possible to merge `Row` and `Column` components together to create a grid?

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Pane {
    anchors.fill: parent
    Row {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Column {
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            Rectangle {border.color: "red";color: "blue"; anchors.left: parent.left;anchors.right: parent.right; height: parent.height;width: parent.width}
        }
        Column {
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            Rectangle {border.color: "red";color: "green";anchors.left: parent.left;anchors.right: parent.right; height: parent.height; width: parent.width}
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with Qt 5.8, an empty white screen is what I am getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are setting the `width` of the `Rectangle`s to the `width` of their respective parent `Column`s. But these don't have any `width` set in turn.

Try setting the `width` of both `Column`s as follows:

```
width: parent.width / 2
```

This should split the row into the two `Column`s. I'm assuming this is the behaviour you are looking for, if not you could try a QML [`Grid`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-grid.html) control to get a finer grain control over the layout.

Comment: The key point to understand about `Row` and `Column` components is that they do not calculate widths or heights, they just place items in a consecutive order. That was my mistake.